# How is a PhD applicant's potential as a researcher evaluated?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science, recommendation-letter

I have been approaching PhD applications under these assumptions:

- The focus is mostly on the letters of recommendation.
- Every admitted applicant has several letters that make a convincing argument that the he would be an extremely successful researcher in the given field.
- These letters are only credible if they are from reputable professional researchers who know the applicant well.

But how much evidence is necessary to show that the applicant would be a successful researcher? First, what does the recommendation letter author need to see in the student to make that argument sincerely, and how much interaction is necessary before the author knows the student well enough to make that judgment? Second, what evidence does the admissions committee need to read in order to believe that argument?

(I am studying computer science in the US, if it makes a difference.)

Comment: Often you can't determine if someone will be a successful researcher until decades after their PhD.  And even then, you can't determine if they will be a successful researcher in the future, only in the past.

Comment: @Kimball Not disagreeing with you, but: how else to identify the elite among a set of college graduates who were all outstanding students to begin with? Assuming the top <10% of graduates apply and <10% of applicants are admitted, what distinguishes the top <10% of the top <10% from the rest of the top <10%? Undergraduate admissions solve this very problem with interviews and holistic reviews -- they look for great people, not just great students. But if all a PhD program cares about is the quality of research that a student produces while enrolled, then what exactly do admissions _look_ for?

Comment: I'm not at a top school, but I usually don't try to evaluate research potential at all.  Rather I look for how bright, dedicated and well prepared the candidates are.  (This comes from my experience in pure math, where most applicants haven't had much or any research experience, and it's generally advised that the best way to prepare for math grad school is learn serious math, rather than try to do undergrad research.)

Answer (score 4):

- The author is supposed to be able to discern and determine some strengths from
  the applicant's personality and his academic procedure, could which
  considered as valuable points in her view point, to be known and
  succeeded as a graduate student. As an instance, the author might
  praise his teaching capabilities, based on his benevolence to help
  the other students to understand the academic subjects, in a better
  form. As an another example, she might assess him as an assiduous
  person, as he had summarized many articles to conflate his essay's
  introduction, systematically. More interaction she had with the applicant, more
  robust explanation she would present about the person... As a matter
  of fact, the author can focus on every positive aspect of the
  applicant and try to elaborate the details, reasonably...
- Readers do not often expect any official evidence for the asserted
  points within the LoR. They would be convinced by the letter's
  credibility, if the author has shown the relevance between the level
  of the support for the person and the depth of the relationship with
  him. Obviously, knowing the author's identity would act as an indispensable factor to authorize the LoR and its content.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Mantinking's answer, here are some of the helpful insights.

- *The focus is mostly on the letters of recommendation.*

Your undergrad/master theses weighs the same amount of importance(even more in some cases) as the recommendation letters and you should have research experience in more or less a related field to the group you are applying.
**A good recommendation stamps credibility qualitatively whereas a good master thesis(publications) communicates potential quantitatively.**

- *Every admitted applicant has several letters that make a convincing argument that the he would be an extremely successful researcher in the given field.*

Most institutes will specify the number of recommendation letters, *several* may be a bit confusing. From my experience, 2 would be sufficient in most cases. The letter would have additional impact if it comes from your thesis adviser or a co author. *extremely successful* is relative phrase, lets base it on the gross impact factor. I had only one recommendation from a *average successful* researcher, still got into a good research lab. I had a strong thesis though.